# How to correct the missing citation counts/citing References in the adsabs.harvard?

Tags: citations, arxiv, website, online-resource

How could we correct the missing citation counts and the missing citing References in the [adsabs.harvard](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/)?

For example, I find that other resources such as https://inspirehep.net/ that have much precise and better citation counts, while both the Google Scholar and [adsabs.harvard](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/) misses some citation counts/missing citing References.

---

These three resources have their own advantages and disadvantages:

1) [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/): Google scholar miss citations from arXiv (sometimes but not always).

2) [adsabs.harvard](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/): In principle, it counts everything in arXiv, but even if so, the bib format citations may be missing -- perhaps it is the LaTex generating issue.

3) https://inspirehep.net, it only counts articles that are relevant to particle physics, high-energy theory, quantum field and string theory. It misses other disciplines such as Atomic-Molecule Optics or Condensed Matter physics.

---

I am happy to receive comments from experts working in all disciplines.

Answer (score 4):

For NASA's ADS at least, there's a "submit missing references" form available [here](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/feedback/missingreferences).

(note that this link is dysfunctional if one doesn't allow the site to set browser cookies)